# Need seam removal algorithm when pasting a patch to a grayscale image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I have a grayscale image and I paste a patch into it. Consider the following:

[image]

I want to conform the patch to the original image so the border between the patch and original image is less obvious. Let's say we can manipulate 5 pixels on the border of source image or the patch.

The algorithm should have O(N) complexity. Currently I'm using [Shepard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting) to do the job but it's too damn slow.

For every pixel it is known that if it is form the patch or the original image. Also the coordinates of border pixels are known.

Comment: you can put over a small 3x3 gauss filter (only at the edges)

Comment: @Thomas That's very close to what I need except that the local details should remain but gaussian blur will smooth them too. And on the other hand it has big calculaltion per pixel (consider a 10 pixel radius). Maybe a modified version can do the trick.

Comment: If you use cuda or openCL, you can program the algorithm on GPU. It is very easy to do parallel

Comment: @Thomas That's a good advice.